# Visual Studio 2013 Publish Disable "Preview"

Tags: visual-studio-2013, publish-profiles

When I'm in VS I occasionally want to rapidly push changes. When I go to the "publish" prompt it forces a preview window. See below. I have to explicitly press "publish" again. Is there anyway to just straight publish?

Also is there a keyboard shortcut for this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show the `Web One Click Publish` toolbar and you can publish by clicking the `Publish Web` button

You can also create a keyboard shortcut for `Build.PublishSelection` which will display the publish dialog.  Pressing Enter when the dialog shows will deploy using your default profile.

Comment: Ok this is working awesome! I wish I could skip the ENTER though on the keyboard shortcut. Any thoughts there?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't see any way to bind the "Publish Web" button to a shortcut key.  The only Publish option I can find that can be bound involves displaying the publish dialog.